# the same audio have different length using different tools (librosa,ffprobe)

Tags: python, audio, ffmpeg, ffprobe, librosa

I want to measure an audio file's duration.
I'm using two different tools and got different values.

1. ffprobe:
   I'm using this line to get duration using ffprobe

```
 ffprobe -i audio.m4a -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0"
```

result :`780.320000` seconds
 2. Librosa (python library)
and using this line to get duartion using librosa

```
y1, sr1 = librosa.load(audio_path, sr=44100)
librosa.get_duration(y1, sr1) * 1000
```

result `780329.7959183673` milliseconds

Does anyone know what's causing the difference?

Comment: I'd have a look at the units. ffprobe returns almost exactly 1/1000th of librosa.

Comment: @nathan I'm sorry can you clarify more? what do you mean by units? 
could you provide an example for "ffprobe returns almost exactly 1/1000th of librosa"?

Comment: Are you sure ffprobe returns milliseconds and librosa returns seconds?

Comment: @Nathan both return milliseconds.

Comment: ffprobe returns seconds.

Comment: So why do you mutliply the second with a thousand? Then you're comparing milliseconds to microseconds

Comment: @Nathan I meant the output of two lines in the question in milliseconds

Comment: @Gyan you are right, I'm multiplying it later by 1000 in my code
 what I meant is the value still didn't match

Comment: How do you obtain `y1` and `sr1` in the call to `get_duration`? Can you extend your code example to show this?

Comment: @ROpdebee this is how i obtain them

`y1, sr1 = librosa.load(audio_path, sr=44100)`

Answer (score 2):

This is likely just normal floating  point error. The two libraries probably make mathematically similar computations, but use different internal representation of the values which produce small rounding errors. This is normal and expected in floating point numbers.